# OpenSSL version mismatch. Built against 1000105f, you have 10001080

Tags: ssh, openssl, debian

I just ran `apt-get upgrade`, and according to /var/log/apt/history.log, openssl has been updated to version 1.0.1e-2+rvt+deb7u7. Now I have one SSH session still open, but I can't open another one. I restarted SSH, which returned `OpenSSL version mismatch. Built against 1000105f, you have 10001080`. 
I tried `apt-get remove openssl && apt-get install openssl` with no luck. I'm running debian on a raspberry pi.

Update: moved to [Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/764873/cant-open-an-ssh-session-because-of-openssl-version-mismatch)

Comment: What Linux distribution are you running? Please edit the question with all the details.

Comment: This can happen if you build SSH against one version of OpenSSL (say 1.0.2o) and then later update to GitHub stable version 1.0.2 (OpenSSL_1_0_2-stable). SSH will detect the patch number mismatch and not run. I believe you also need to build with `-Wl,-R,<OpenSSL path>` and/or `-Wl,--enable-new-dtags`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try `apt-get install openssh-server openssh-client`.

I had the same issue when I updated my system to Debian Testing. Even though SSH was already installed, in my case it wasn't pulled in for updating when I ran `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` and so the system still had the same SSH binaries with the now-outdated libraries linked against it, hence the version mismatch.

Answer (score 2):

I hit this error the following error in my Ubuntu.

```
OpenSSL version mismatch. Built against 100020bf, you have 1000106f
```

Here are what I did to fix the issue.

1. Check where is ssh

   ```
   \#which ssh

   /usr/local/bin/ssh
   ```
2. Remove the current ssh package.

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove openssh-server openssh-client
   ```
3. Remove ssh file under /usr/local/bin/ssh
4. Reinstall ssh package as follows.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install openssh-server openssh-client
   ```
5. Log out the current session and re-login again. SSH command is back to work and is under /usr/bin/ssh.

   ```
   \#which ssh

   /usr/bin/ssh
   ```

Answer (score 2):

As OpenSSL promises ABI compatibility on major versions (1.x..), no application should complain if the version of the library increases.  In the OP the built-version seems less than the library version, and there should not be a problem.

This seems like a bug in OpenSSH.
The solution unfortunately is to make sure that packages are updated at the same time, which may not always be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your **other** SSL packages have the same version number that your openssl package does. Things like libssl1.0.0 and libssl-dev may have a higher or lower version if you've used non-standard repos like debian-testing.

So if your openssl version is, for example, 1.0.1e-2+deb7u11, fixing this is as simple as

```
apt-get install libssl1.0.0=1.0.1e-2+deb7u11
```

Answer (score 0):

I will deprecate the answer below because I just discovered with `which ssh` that I am using a version of OpenSSH that I compiled on my own.

```
# which ssh
/usr/local/bin/ssh
```

After deleting my local ssh, `openssh-server` and `openssh-client` successfully installed.

---

I encountered this and used the similar technique I used to fix https://askubuntu.com/a/854145/348754.

I encountered the following error.

```
Creating SSH2 ECDSA key; this may take some time ...OpenSSL version mismatch. Built against 1000106f, you have 1000207f
dpkg: error processing package openssh-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 255
```

I have to edit /var/lib/dpkg/info/openssh-server.postinst and comment the following lines.

```
#create_key "Creating SSH2 ECDSA key; this may take some time ..." \
#       "$hostkeys" /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key -t ecdsa
#create_key "Creating SSH2 ED25519 key; this may take some time ..." \
#       "$hostkeys" /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key -t ed25519
```

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure that any other installed package did not bring its own openssl library and added itself to your environment.

One such culprit I just found is the "Max View Storage Manager" from Microsemi. (Yes, I mention that name to shame the developers.) It adds itself to:

- LD_LIBRARY_PATH
- PWD
- OPENSSL_HOME
- OPENSSL_BIN
- PATH

ssh worked fine as root (where these additional entries were not added) but failed as my normal user.

Answer (score 0):

All of the answers here didn't work with me. You can install the latest version of openssl manually by following this steps

- https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-openssl-from-source-on-linux/

Then install openssh manually from their repo.

- https://www.tecmint.com/install-openssh-server-from-source-in-linux/

I faced that issue when I tried to run vagrant ssh into a box where my ssh client didn't have the correct openssl version compiled against it.