# OpenSSL version mismatch. Built against 1010106f, you have 1010007f

Tags: openssl, openssh

I have a ubuntu 20.04 container. I have openssl installed

```
root@sddfr4533:/# openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022
```

I am getting this error when trying to clone some project containing libcrypto.so.1.1

```
/usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-http: /software/bin/libcrypto.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_1' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh.so.4)
```

also when I try to remove and reinstall openssh (apt-get install openssh-server openssh-client) , I am receiving this error:

```
Creating config file /etc/ssh/sshd_config with new version
Creating SSH2 RSA key; this may take some time ...OpenSSL version mismatch. Built against 1010106f, you have 1010007f
```

I have already tried solutions on these threads:
[OpenSSL version mismatch. Built against 1000105f, you have 10001080](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24096069/openssl-version-mismatch-built-against-1000105f-you-have-10001080)

and

[OpenSSL version mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47367627/openssl-version-mismatch)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was related to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH set for my program /software/bin/.
That cause having multiple versions.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this while doing a `git push`, and here is how I solved it:

- I updated the `openssh-server` and `openssh-client` on my system by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47455656/13584363). This did not work out, but there was no harm in updating these libraries to their latest versions:

  ```
  sudo apt install openssh-server openssh-client
  ```
- I then removed the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` which I had set up while I was working on a different thing. [[An answer to this current question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74432503/13584363) indirectly inspired me to do so]

I then ran `source ~/.zshrc` but things still did not work out.

I restarted my terminal, and voila! It worked!

Here are the required info on my system's configuration:

> OS: **Ubuntu 22.04**
>
> Shell: **zsh**

Answer (score 0):

when after an upgrade , ssh respectivly sshd ( with path ) , say openssl version mismatch and wont run
i had just one now , '2023 , and all search revealed as always crap
a mate restored'' my serv after couldnt find much out
now a day later i tried updating ( i also -t experimental some , rule is " dont dist-upgrade to expwrimental , only upgrqde " )
and there was the ssh + sshd not wanna run again
luckily im some more clear now and managed easily to                                overwrite that error by compiling ssh ( ' openssh-* ' package )
the debian way

i include -t experimental as i used it
if u dont like -t exp.. u can omit that option ..
i also root only , mowtly

and is implied to be in a dir suitable for src + compilation + resulting deb / udeb

```
apt source openssh
apt build-dep openssh
apt -t experimental upgrade libsystemd0-
apt satisfy openssh
apt -t experimental install build-essential
cd openssh-9.2p1/
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
dpkg -i ../openssh-{client,server,sftp-server}*.deb
dpkg -i ../openssh-{client,server,sftp-server}*.deb
/etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

twice dpkg -i to simply make the error related to old version away .. for convience ..
greets , xmb sw

missing : dpkg hold openssh .. not sure